# Can not download coursera video because of data-reactid, How can I get the downloadable link?

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

I am trying to download some coursera videos but can not find downloadable links. All I find is "data-reactid" tags. How can I get a downloadable link ?

Here is the inspect-element code:

```
<span class="inline-child rc-EffortText caption-text color-secondary-text text-hint" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.1.0.2.4.0.$Eywv6.2.0.$o1GcU.1:$qxJHd.0.0.0.3.1.1">18 min</span>
```

I am using python.

Comment: Your scraper / parser needs to support Javascript. You may want to try PhantomJS.

Comment: I am using selenium but if I can not get the downloadable link I can not download it. Just asking is there anyway I can get teh CDN for the videos ?